# Tensorflow DNNRegressor error when model is saved?

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am using DNNRegressor as the fitness function of a genetic algorithm so I need to execute it thousands of times and then save the model in each iteration. The light version of the code is showed here. The simulation goes well after some point and then an error appear and the simulation stops. I am using Tensorflow 1.0.1 if you have any advice to solve this problem I'll appreciate a lot your help.

The error:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:
>   Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to get matching
>   files on
>   /home/xxxx/workspace2/NNEvolution/4_15_136/6/model.ckpt-1500:
>   Resource exhausted: /home/xxxx/workspace2/NNEvolution/4_15_136/6
>   [[Node: save/RestoreV2_5 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save/Const_0, save/RestoreV2_5/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_5/shape_and_slices)]]
>   [[Node: save/RestoreV2_7/_7 = _Recvclient_terminated=false,
>   recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_6_save/RestoreV2_7",
>   tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]]
>
> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Unsuccessful
>   TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to get matching files on
>   /home/xxxx/workspace2/NNEvolution/4_15_136/6/model.ckpt-1500:
>   Resource exhausted: /home/xxxx/workspace2/NNEvolution/4_15_136/6
>   [[Node: save/RestoreV2_5 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save/Const_0, save/RestoreV2_5/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_5/shape_and_slices)]]
>   [[Node: save/RestoreV2_7/_7 = _Recvclient_terminated=false,
>   recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_6_save/RestoreV2_7",
>   tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]]
>
> Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11:
>   SIGSEGV)

Details of the code here:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import shutil

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
def FitnessFunction ( hhLayer, epoch, pathModel, train_set, val_set, test_set, every_n_steps, early_stopping_rounds, nnExperiment, gaExperiment, gaGeneration, globalIndCounter ):
    avgMSE = 0
    # Data sets
    config1 = tf.ConfigProto()
    config1.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    feature_columns = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("")]
    for nnExp in range(0, nnExperiment):
        validation_monitor = tf.contrib.learn.monitors.ValidationMonitor(
            val_set.data,
            val_set.target,
            every_n_steps=every_n_steps,
            early_stopping_metric="loss",
            early_stopping_metric_minimize=False,
            early_stopping_rounds=early_stopping_rounds)
        #validation_monitor = tf.contrib.learn.monitors.ValidationMonitor(
        #    val_set.data,
         #   val_set.target,
         #   every_n_steps=every_n_steps,
         #   early_stopping_metric="loss",
         #   early_stopping_metric_minimize=True)
        # Specify that all features have real-value data
        strName = str(gaExperiment) + "_" + str(gaGeneration)+ "_"+str(globalIndCounter)
        #indPath = pathModel + "/" + strName +"/" + str( nnExp ) +"/"+ "model.ckpt"

        indPath = os.path.join( os.path.sep, pathModel, strName, str( nnExp ) )
        #if (os.path.isdir(pathModel)):
        #    shutil.rmtree(pathModel)
        #Creating the model
        #mlp = tf.contrib.learn.DNNRegressor( feature_columns=feature_columns, hidden_units=hhLayer, optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4), model_dir=pathModel, enable_centered_bias = True, dropout=0.4)
        #mlp = tf.contrib.learn.DNNRegressor(feature_columns=feature_columns, hidden_units=hhLayer,
        #                                    optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4), model_dir=pathModel,
        #                                    enable_centered_bias=True)
        #try:

        mlp = tf.contrib.learn.DNNRegressor(feature_columns=feature_columns, hidden_units=hhLayer, model_dir=indPath, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,enable_centered_bias=True,
                                            dropout=0.01, config=tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(gpu_memory_fraction=0.30, save_checkpoints_secs= 43200) )
        #except:
        #    a=1

        #mlp = tf.contrib.learn.DNNRegressor(feature_columns=feature_columns, hidden_units=hhLayer, model_dir=pathModel, enable_centered_bias=True, optimizer=tf.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1, l1_regularization_strength=0.001), dropout=0.01)
        # optimizer=tf.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1, l1_regularization_strength=0.001 )

        # Trainning the model.
        #try:
        mlp.fit( x=train_set.data, y=train_set.target, steps=epoch, monitors=[validation_monitor], batch_size=50 )
        #except:
        #    a=1

        MSE = mlp.evaluate( x=test_set.data, y=test_set.target)["loss"]

            # Classify two new flower samples.
        # new_samples = np.array(
        #    [[6.4, 3.2, 4.5, 1.5], [5.8, 3.1, 5.0, 1.7]], dtype=float)
        # y = list(classifier.predict(new_samples))
        # print("Predictions: {}".format(str(y)))
        avgMSE = avgMSE + MSE
        del mlp
    return (avgMSE/nnExperiment)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Data sets
    #config = tf.ConfigProto()
    #config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True

    IRIS_TRAINING   = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "boston_train.csv")
    IRIS_VAL        = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "boston_val.csv")
    IRIS_TEST       = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "boston_test.csv")

    train_set       = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header( filename=IRIS_TRAINING,  target_dtype=np.float, features_dtype=np.float )
    val_set         = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header( filename=IRIS_VAL,       target_dtype=np.float, features_dtype=np.float )
    test_set        = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header( filename=IRIS_TEST,      target_dtype=np.float, features_dtype=np.float )

    #initialPath     = "/home/xxxx/workspace2/NNEvolution"
    initialPath     = os.path.join( os.path.sep, 'home', 'xxxx', 'workspace2', 'NNEvolution' )
    if ( os.path.isdir( initialPath ) ):
        shutil.rmtree( initialPath )
    idxCount        = 1
    for exp in range(0,50):
        for ger in range(0,30):
                mse         = FitnessFunction( [30,30,30,30], 1500, initialPath, train_set, val_set, test_set, 1, 200, nnExperiment=10, gaExperiment=exp,  gaGeneration=ger, globalIndCounter=idxCount)
                idxCount    = idxCount +1
                print("MSE: {0:f}".format(mse))
```

[image: GPU details]